# Unable to query pinecone vector index using filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-embedding, pinecone

I am having issues trying to query my pinecone index with a filter. It works without the filter however. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I have upserted into pinecone in the following way:

```
for doc in tqdm(docs_restaurant):
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(str(doc.metadata))
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        documents.append({
            'id': f'{doc.page_content}_{i}',
            'text': chunk,
            'metadata': {
                'file': 'restaurants'
            }
        })

for i in tqdm(range(0, len(documents), batch_size)):
    i_end = min(len(documents), i+batch_size)
    res = s.post(
        f"{endpoint_url}/upsert",
        headers=headers,
        json={
            "documents": documents[i:i_end]
        }
    )
```

The data is in pinecone. I can query it with no filter successfully ala:

```
query_response = self.index.query(
                    top_k=query.top_k,
                    vector=query.embedding,
                    filter=None,
                    include_metadata=True,
                )
```

Which returns the following:

```
{'matches': [{'id': 'Del Taco_0_1',
               'metadata': {'document_id': 'Del Taco_0',
                            'file': 'restaurants',
                            'text': "pic Beyond Burritos', 'Desserts & Shakes', "
                                    "'Tacos', 'Meals', '20 Under $2 Menu']}"},
               'score': 0.786260903,
               'values': []},
              {'id': 'Minos Take Out_0_1',
               'metadata': {'document_id': 'Minos Take Out_0',
                            'file': 'restaurants',
                            'text': "izers', 'Wraps & Pitas', 'Light Meals']}"},
               'score': 0.7722193,
               'values': []},
'namespace': ''
}
```

However, when I try this:

```
self.index.query(
top_k=query.top_k,
vector=query.embedding,
filter={'file': {'$eq': 'restaurants'}},
include_metadata=True,)
```

It returns nothing:

```
{'matches': [], 'namespace': ''}
```

Comment: you were able to solve this?

Comment: yes, the code turned out to be fine.. For some reason I had to terminate the pinecone index and rebuild it. Filtering worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `'restaurants'` with `['restaurants']`

So the code should be:

```py
self.index.query(
  top_k=query.top_k,
  vector=query.embedding,
  filter={'file': {'$eq': ['restaurants']}},
  include_metadata=True,)
```

dq